# setting up webDav on mamp

Tags: php, macos, webdav

i am reading this article http://manas.tungare.name/blog/howto-setup-webdav-on-mac-os-x-leopard-for-syncing-omnifocus-to-iphone/

and it says how to setup a webdav but its doing it through the web sharring routh throuhg mac options but i have mamp setup and i was following along until i saw the alias setup of this folder /Library/WebServer/WebDAV and the problem is i dont have that folder nor the files in it. how do i get these files? do i need to have osx server installed or can i do this through snow leopard ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Author of the [article you cited](http://manas.tungare.name/blog/howto-setup-webdav-on-mac-os-x-leopard-for-syncing-omnifocus-to-iphone/) here.

That's a new folder you would create to store all the files you wanted to share via WebDAV. It doesn't exist on a stock Mac OS X install.